# Last line of text overflowing out of mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

[image: Last line of text breaks "affordably" incorrectly]

The top section title of `DataSN enables everyone to easily make use of data of all websites on the Internet, flexibly and affordably.` on [this page](https://datasn.io/pages/about-us) is behaving weird in that the last line of text is overflowing out of the screen on mobile devices such as "iPhone 6/7/8" with Chrome developer tools.

Tried `overflow: auto` which only makes it scrollable horizontally and `word-break: break-word;` which breaks the last word `affordably` by half.

Neither of the solutions is ideal. It's weird that it behaves in this manner. Shouldn't it be auto wrapped just like how it is for the previous lines? How to make it wrap by word for the last line here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `&nbsp;` between words.. nbsp stands for no-break space. And hence these words don't wrap around the space.

[image]

After changing `&nbsp;` to simple space

[image]